# Let $H$ and $K$ be two conjugate subgroups in $G.$ Show that $N_G(H)$ and $N_G(K)$ are conjugates.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $H$ and $K$ be two conjugate subgroups in $G.$ Show that $N_G(H)$ and $N_G(K)$ are conjugates

I thought of using the second part of Sylow's Theorem that says; In particular, any two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate in $G$.

But I'm not sure if I have to prove that $H$ and $K$ are $p$-subgroups

Comment: Try something else, as no information is given about the orders of $H$ and $K$..

Comment: You're right, didn't thought about that

Comment: can we say that there is a $gHg^{-1}=K$ and conversely?

Comment: Yes, being conjugate subgroups means that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $G$, there exists a $g\in G$ such that $H=gKg^{-1}$.

Consider $$N_G(K)=\{x\in G\mid xK=Kx\}.$$

Observe that

$$\begin{align}
gN_G(K)g^{-1}&=g\{x\in G\mid xK=Kx\} g^{-1}\\
&=\{gxg^{-1}\in G\mid xK=Kx\}\\
&=\{y=gxg^{-1}\in G\mid xKx^{-1}=K\}\\
&=\{y\in G\mid g^{-1}ygKg^{-1}y^{-1}g=K\}\\
&=\{y\in G\mid g^{-1}yHy^{-1}g=K\}\\
&=\{y\in G\mid yHy^{-1}=gKg^{-1}=H\}\\
&=\{y\in G\mid yH=Hy\}\\
&=N_G(H).
\end{align}$$

Hence they are conjugate in $G$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: try to prove that $N_G(H^g)=N_G(H)^g$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ and element $g \in G$.

Answer (score 3):

If $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $G$, then they belong to the same orbit of the action of $G$ by conjugation on the set of the subgroups of $G$, and thence their stabilizers are conjugate. But such stabilizers are precisely $N_G(H)$ and $N_G(K)$, respectively.